# Price factor option for products

Tags: price, custom-options

is it possible to attribute every product with an price factor that is used for the calculation of the final price but not shown in the frontend.

In my special case the base price refers to 1000 pieces but every product is sold as an package of e.g. 2500 pieces (differs for every product). So my price factor would be 2.5.

Thanks so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only for display issues you do display a base price per unit there is a baseprice extension out there where you can specifiy the price for a given amount of units. 
Like your package is 2500grams and another has 2750grams you can setup a base price of XX $ / 1000grams for better price comparability for the customer. At least here in germany this is also demanded by law to empower the customer to not be fooled by package sizes.

Comment: @OliverSchmidt: if this answer helper you to resolve your problem, then feel free to accept it by clicking on the tick button that is availble in the left sectionof this answer

Comment: Is there a way to calculate with the base price of the extension?

Comment: As far as i know it is for display purpose only. so if you have something with 2500 units and a package price it can calculate the price per X units itself but nothing more fancy.

Answer (score 0):

The price should be set for the sale unit or allow people to buy your product in increments.
So if you sell your product in boxes of 2500 pieces, you can set the price to be for 2500 pieces and name your product `Box of 2500 of "product name here"`.
This way qty = 1 means one box of 2500.
Or the second approach could be to set the price for 1 unit and in the inventory tab set the qty increments to 2500.
This way the customer would see how much one product costs but can only buy in boxes of 2500.

I don't see a point where you would want the price for 1000 items but sell them in 2500 boxes.  Seams strange to me.
The 2 methods I described are far easier than what you want to do. They involve no coding.
Changing the way the prices work in Magento can easily lead to a long an painful path that ends nowhere.